# modelling a curvy tap

Tags: modeling

how do I make curvy surfaces(red) of the tap while having other surfaces very flat and hard(blue)?

[image: the bottom part is curvy and the red part is hard n flat]

here is a 2d diagram of it[image]

I am sure that we have to use a deform modifier but how do i start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having round and flat parts is mainly matter of supporting edges (to make parts flatter than other).

[image]

Start with a circle (for instance 16 vertices) and extrude it up 3 times.

The first time as support loop. The second as bottom of the faucet and third for its top.

Then extrude the front faces part of the last extrusion, to make the faucet itself.

Close the top respecting quads (or almost).

Add a subdivision modifier (set it to 2, for instance).

Add loop cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (the support edges) and drive it to the edges you want to harden.
In this model, these supporting edges are the following:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use an edge crease on the edges you want "straight" and then use a Subdivision Surface Modifier:

[image: Crease2]

[image: Crease2]